# Path to matlab.settings

Tags: matlab

How to get Matlab's path to matlab.settings?

On Unix/Mac this folder is usually `~/.matlab/R20xx/`.

It's also where `javaclasspath.txt` is located.

I want to get it programmatically inside Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obtained in a system-independent way by using the [`prefdir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/prefdir.html) command

```
disp(prefdir)

%//  /Users/suever/.matlab/R2015b
```